# Post-doc independent money/grant (astrophysics/computer science) in the US (travel expense/workshop)?

Tags: funding, postdocs, nsf, awards

I am currently a postdoc in a US University (I'm French).

I am in between astrophysics and computer science.

My work is currently funded by NSF (work related to the Dark Energy Survey).

Are there some program/award/grant out there I could apply to, to gain some autonomy (additional funding I could use in the way I want to for travel expenses/collaborations/organizing workshop).

Because my problem is that most program I've found are either for PhD students or for professors. What about post-docs?

Answer (score 1):

Due to their (traditionally) short terms, postdocs are usually limited in what they can apply for. There are [NSF Postdoctoral Fellowhips](https://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=5291) in your area, as well as almost every other area NSF funds. The other funding agencies in the US (DoE, NIH, etc.) also have fellowships available for postdocs. You should search the Internet more carefully for other opportunities.

That being said, whatever grant is funding your work almost certainly has travel funding included in it. Have you talked with your supervisor or PI about the kind of travel you'd like to do? You should.

Comment: I have travel funding but just for conferences directly related to the main project. For aside projects (related inderictly to the main one), I don't have funding for my travel expenses.

Comment: There may be money you can get from your department for side projects if you explain to your department head why that would be important to you (and them!).

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the organization part of your question, there are NSF grants specifically targeted to support conference and workshop organization.  To get one of those, you will likely need support from your PI, but these can be fairly fast and relatively easy to get.

An easier and cheaper way to organize workshops in many cases, however, is to attach them to an existing large event in your field.  This has the advantage that it can be easier to get the people you want to come, because they are likely to already be coming to the main event, and often the costs are covered entirely by the main event.